# I never withdrew

Tags: bug, status-completed, election

In the election it says that I withdrew on Novermber 7th 2011.

I did no such thing.

I was originally withdrawn due to badge restrictions, but since then I was put back.

How can we remedy this?

Comment: +1. I'm in the same boat here.

Comment: There you have it: no screen capture, no history! ;-)

Comment: @Arjan yea, that was a mistake on my part ... whoops. will know for next time ^_^

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Judging by the [election page](https://stackoverflow.com/election/2?tab=primary), this issue seems to have been fixed.

Comment: and that puts us 20 minutes behind everyone :-(

Comment: Yes, it seems so :/ Perhaps we could get a little extra time at the top to compensate?

Comment: You also benefit from a little more exposition than the others because of this very incident. Maybe that will cancel out the twenty minute gap.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Good point!

Comment: I will give both of you a vote to help correct this injustice.